# skimage module lacking documented features

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to play with image processing on python, and was recommended the use of the skimage module (Scikit-image full name).

I am using a Windows Conda Python 2.7 installation.

When trying to use the canny function,`skimage.feature.canny()`, I ran into the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'canny'`
```

Printing out the module version, I appear to be updated.

```
print skimage.__version__
0.10.1
```

According to [documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.canny) though, this function should exist.

I'm not entirely sure what to do from here. Any help?

EDIT -

```
>>> print dir(skimage.feature)
['BRIEF', 'CENSURE', 'ORB', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '_daisy', '_hessian_det_appx', '_hog', '_texture', 'blob', 'blob_dog', 'blob_doh', 'blob_log', 'brief', 'brief_cy', 'censure', 'censure_cy', 'corner', 'corner_cy', 'corner_fast', 'corner_foerstner', 'corner_harris', 'corner_kitchen_rosenfeld', 'corner_moravec', 'corner_orientations', 'corner_peaks', 'corner_shi_tomasi', 'corner_subpix', 'daisy', 'greycomatrix', 'greycoprops', 'hessian_matrix', 'hessian_matrix_det', 'hessian_matrix_eigvals', 'hog', 'local_binary_pattern', 'match', 'match_descriptors', 'match_template', 'orb', 'orb_cy', 'peak', 'peak_local_max', 'plot_matches', 'structure_tensor', 'structure_tensor_eigvals', 'template', 'texture', 'util']
```

Comment: Why not try `print dir(skimage.feature)` to see all the attributes?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. See edit. Canny is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `skimage.filter.canny`(previous place). This should be in the right place(`skimage.feature.canny`) in release 0.10.1-2. Related discussion [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/1113)

Comment: Is this a simple case of outdated documentation? Shocked. Thanks!

Comment: @jhc, more or less. Actually documentation is ahead.

Comment: The documentation should be matched with the version--so, for version 0.10, read the documentation here: http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.10.x/

Comment: I don't even have any filter or features (!) The package is installed using the prebuilt binary by Gohlke (.whl file, version 0.11.3)

Comment: @JimRaynor, please run the example [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.feature.html?highlight=canny#canny) and post your error message in a new question.